# core dump for apt-cache update

Tags: apt, apt-cache

I am trying to update my apt cache, but after a few hits I get this error

[image]

```
semantic@semantic-Tech:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for semantic: 
Hit:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease          
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release            
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                             
Fetched 102 kB in 8s (11.4 kB/s)                                                                                                              
*** Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000172e250 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ff8aa1007e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7ff8aa10937a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7ff8aa10d53c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_component_complete+0x439)[0x7ff8aa485d19]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_data_pool_update+0x44a)[0x7ff8aa486f0a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_cache_builder_refresh+0x1c2)[0x7ff8aa47c272]
appstreamcli(ascli_refresh_cache+0x12e)[0x4049de]
appstreamcli(as_client_run+0x6fb)[0x403ceb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff8aa0a9830]
appstreamcli(_start+0x29)[0x403519]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18874418                           /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00607000-00608000 r--p 00007000 08:01 18874418                           /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00608000-00609000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 18874418                           /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00a4a000-025a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ff8a0000000-7ff8a0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a0021000-7ff8a4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a4857000-7ff8a4862000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19268006                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7ff8a4862000-7ff8a4a62000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 19268006                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7ff8a4a62000-7ff8a4a63000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 19268006                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7ff8a4a63000-7ff8a4a64000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 19268006                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7ff8a4a64000-7ff8a4a9a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19139671                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7ff8a4a9a000-7ff8a4c9a000 ---p 00036000 08:01 19139671                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7ff8a4c9a000-7ff8a4c9f000 r--p 00036000 08:01 19139671                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7ff8a4c9f000-7ff8a4ca0000 rw-p 0003b000 08:01 19139671                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7ff8a4ca0000-7ff8a4cb9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19268010                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7ff8a4cb9000-7ff8a4eb9000 ---p 00019000 08:01 19268010                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7ff8a4eb9000-7ff8a4ebc000 r--p 00019000 08:01 19268010                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7ff8a4ebc000-7ff8a4ebd000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 19268010                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7ff8a4ebd000-7ff8a587c000 r--p 00000000 08:01 18881343                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7ff8a587c000-7ff8a7132000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882913                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7ff8a7132000-7ff8a7331000 ---p 018b6000 08:01 18882913                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7ff8a7331000-7ff8a7332000 r--p 018b5000 08:01 18882913                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7ff8a7332000-7ff8a7333000 rw-p 018b6000 08:01 18882913                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7ff8a7333000-7ff8a7337000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266803                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ff8a7337000-7ff8a7536000 ---p 00004000 08:01 266803                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ff8a7536000-7ff8a7537000 r--p 00003000 08:01 266803                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ff8a7537000-7ff8a7538000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 266803                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7ff8a7538000-7ff8a7640000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268849                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7ff8a7640000-7ff8a783f000 ---p 00108000 08:01 268849                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7ff8a783f000-7ff8a7840000 r--p 00107000 08:01 268849                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7ff8a7840000-7ff8a7841000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 268849                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7ff8a7841000-7ff8a7862000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266686                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7ff8a7862000-7ff8a7a61000 ---p 00021000 08:01 266686                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7ff8a7a61000-7ff8a7a62000 r--p 00020000 08:01 266686                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7ff8a7a62000-7ff8a7a63000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 266686                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7ff8a7a63000-7ff8a7be2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882927                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7ff8a7be2000-7ff8a7de2000 ---p 0017f000 08:01 18882927                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7ff8a7de2000-7ff8a7df2000 r--p 0017f000 08:01 18882927                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7ff8a7df2000-7ff8a7df3000 rw-p 0018f000 08:01 18882927                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7ff8a7df3000-7ff8a7df7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a7df7000-7ff8a7dfa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268843                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7ff8a7dfa000-7ff8a7ff9000 ---p 00003000 08:01 268843                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7ff8a7ff9000-7ff8a7ffa000 r--p 00002000 08:01 268843                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7ff8a7ffa000-7ff8a7ffb000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 268843                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7ff8a7ffb000-7ff8a8011000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266657                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff8a8011000-7ff8a8210000 ---p 00016000 08:01 266657                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff8a8210000-7ff8a8211000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 266657                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff8a8211000-7ff8a8383000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18876412                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ff8a8383000-7ff8a8583000 ---p 00172000 08:01 18876412                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ff8a8583000-7ff8a858d000 r--p 00172000 08:01 18876412                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ff8a858d000-7ff8a858f000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 18876412                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ff8a858f000-7ff8a8593000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a8593000-7ff8a85c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18883218                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7ff8a85c3000-7ff8a87c2000 ---p 00030000 08:01 18883218                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7ff8a87c2000-7ff8a87c3000 r--p 0002f000 08:01 18883218                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7ff8a87c3000-7ff8a87c4000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 18883218                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7ff8a87c4000-7ff8a89b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18883578                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7ff8a89b8000-7ff8a8bb8000 ---p 001f4000 08:01 18883578                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7ff8a8bb8000-7ff8a8bbf000 r--p 001f4000 08:01 18883578                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7ff8a8bbf000-7ff8a8bc0000 rw-p 001fb000 08:01 18883578                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7ff8a8bc0000-7ff8a8bdd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18883632                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7ff8a8bdd000-7ff8a8ddd000 ---p 0001d000 08:01 18883632                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7ff8a8ddd000-7ff8a8dde000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 18883632                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7ff8a8dde000-7ff8a8ddf000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 18883632                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7ff8a8ddf000-7ff8a8f8f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18883624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7ff8a8f8f000-7ff8a918e000 ---p 001b0000 08:01 18883624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7ff8a918e000-7ff8a9196000 r--p 001af000 08:01 18883624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7ff8a9196000-7ff8a9198000 rw-p 001b7000 08:01 18883624                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7ff8a9198000-7ff8a9199000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a9199000-7ff8a91a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882618                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7ff8a91a0000-7ff8a939f000 ---p 00007000 08:01 18882618                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7ff8a939f000-7ff8a93a0000 r--p 00006000 08:01 18882618                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7ff8a93a0000-7ff8a93a1000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 18882618                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7ff8a93a1000-7ff8a93b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268846                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7ff8a93b8000-7ff8a95b8000 ---p 00017000 08:01 268846                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7ff8a95b8000-7ff8a95b9000 r--p 00017000 08:01 268846                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7ff8a95b9000-7ff8a95ba000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 268846                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7ff8a95ba000-7ff8a95bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a95bc000-7ff8a95db000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266777                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7ff8a95db000-7ff8a97da000 ---p 0001f000 08:01 266777                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7ff8a97da000-7ff8a97db000 r--p 0001e000 08:01 266777                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7ff8a97db000-7ff8a97dc000 rw-p 0001f000 08:01 266777                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7ff8a97dc000-7ff8a97de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a97de000-7ff8a97f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266528                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7ff8a97f7000-7ff8a99f6000 ---p 00019000 08:01 266528                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7ff8a99f6000-7ff8a99f7000 r--p 00018000 08:01 266528                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7ff8a99f7000-7ff8a99f8000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 266528                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7ff8a99f8000-7ff8a99fb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882749                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8a99fb000-7ff8a9bfa000 ---p 00003000 08:01 18882749                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8a9bfa000-7ff8a9bfb000 r--p 00002000 08:01 18882749                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8a9bfb000-7ff8a9bfc000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 18882749                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8a9bfc000-7ff8a9c14000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268837                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7ff8a9c14000-7ff8a9e13000 ---p 00018000 08:01 268837                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7ff8a9e13000-7ff8a9e14000 r--p 00017000 08:01 268837                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7ff8a9e14000-7ff8a9e15000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 268837                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7ff8a9e15000-7ff8a9e19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8a9e19000-7ff8a9e87000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266748                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7ff8a9e87000-7ff8aa087000 ---p 0006e000 08:01 266748                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7ff8aa087000-7ff8aa088000 r--p 0006e000 08:01 266748                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7ff8aa088000-7ff8aa089000 rw-p 0006f000 08:01 266748                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7ff8aa089000-7ff8aa249000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268854                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ff8aa249000-7ff8aa449000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 268854                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ff8aa449000-7ff8aa44d000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 268854                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ff8aa44d000-7ff8aa44f000 rw-p 001c4000 08:01 268854                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ff8aa44f000-7ff8aa453000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8aa453000-7ff8aa49e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882311                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7ff8aa49e000-7ff8aa69e000 ---p 0004b000 08:01 18882311                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7ff8aa69e000-7ff8aa69f000 r--p 0004b000 08:01 18882311                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7ff8aa69f000-7ff8aa6a0000 rw-p 0004c000 08:01 18882311                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7ff8aa6a0000-7ff8aa6f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882773                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aa6f2000-7ff8aa8f1000 ---p 00052000 08:01 18882773                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aa8f1000-7ff8aa8f2000 r--p 00051000 08:01 18882773                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aa8f2000-7ff8aa8f3000 rw-p 00052000 08:01 18882773                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aa8f3000-7ff8aaa73000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 18882735                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aaa73000-7ff8aac73000 ---p 00180000 08:01 18882735                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aac73000-7ff8aac77000 r--p 00180000 08:01 18882735                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aac77000-7ff8aac79000 rw-p 00184000 08:01 18882735                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aac79000-7ff8aac7b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8aac7b000-7ff8aad89000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 266661                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aad89000-7ff8aaf89000 ---p 0010e000 08:01 266661                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aaf89000-7ff8aaf8a000 r--p 0010e000 08:01 266661                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aaf8a000-7ff8aaf8b000 rw-p 0010f000 08:01 266661                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7ff8aaf8b000-7ff8aaf8c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8aaf8c000-7ff8aafb2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268832                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7ff8ab16c000-7ff8ab18b000 r--s 00000000 08:01 19398888                   /usr/share/mime/mime.cache
7ff8ab18b000-7ff8ab199000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8ab1ae000-7ff8ab1b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8ab1b1000-7ff8ab1b2000 r--p 00025000 08:01 268832                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7ff8ab1b2000-7ff8ab1b3000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 268832                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7ff8ab1b3000-7ff8ab1b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffe304000-7ffffe325000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffffe38f000-7ffffe391000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffffe391000-7ffffe393000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: Please copy terminal outputs as plain text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @muru, thank you for the link, that solved my problem.